# dynamic allocation - pointer to pointer in c

Tags: c

i got exercise from school.

I need to write a function that get array of grades, the size of the array, int number that represent the range of the grades, array that represent the count of the number of the grades in the same range and array that sum the grade of in the range.

1. the function will create sub groups to the grades, for exmaple: if the range of the grades is 10 so that sub groups is: 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39,...,90-99,100.
   the range is 10 so the number of the sub-groups is 100/range + 1 (11 in that example which the range is 10).
2. the function will return array that is pointer to pointer, each element in this array will represent the sub-group by ASC.
   if there is no values in the range (sub-group) we need to set NULL.
3. the count array will count the number of the grade in the same range,
   and the sum array will sum those grades.
   we can assume that the size of those arrays are also 100/range + 1.

important: i need to use dynamic allocate memroy.

i think i have the problem to calculate to which index in the range i need to put the grade, it work in some cases, but not to all.

examples:

```
    int grades[SIZE_GRADES] = {98,45,77,65,89,90,100,43,54,67,55,88,76,67,33,23,45,76,72,76};
    int avg_grd1[100 / GRD_RANGE1 + 1];
    int avg_grd2[100 / GRD_RANGE2 + 1];
    int count_grd1[100 / GRD_RANGE1 + 1];
    int count_grd2[100 / GRD_RANGE2 + 1];
    int** arr1 = GradeStat(grades, SIZE_GRADES, GRD_RANGE1, count_grd1, avg_grd1);
    int** arr2 = GradeStat(grades, SIZE_GRADES, GRD_RANGE2, count_grd2, avg_grd2);

#define GRD_RANGE1 10
#define GRD_RANGE2 7
#define SIZE_GRADES 20
```

those are working for me.
but what i insert this arrays it didn't: (same vars, just different array).

```
    int grades[SIZE_GRADES] = { 45,46,58,68,70,73,74,78,90,94 };

#define GRD_RANGE1 10
#define GRD_RANGE2 15
#define SIZE_GRADES 10
```

and that's my code:

```
int** GradeStat(int* Grades, int size_grades, int grd_range, int* count_grd, int* avg_grd)
{
    int sub_range = 100 / grd_range + 1;
    int** class_grd;
    int place_in_sub_range;

    // alocate memory.
    class_grd = (int**)calloc(sub_range, sizeof(int));
    if (class_grd == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sub_range; i++) {
        count_grd[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sub_range; i++) {
        avg_grd[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_GRADES; i++) {
        // the index (place) in the pointer of pointer.
        place_in_sub_range = Grades[i] / grd_range;

        if (place_in_sub_range <= sub_range) {

            // create new pointer that relevant to the range.
            if (class_grd[place_in_sub_range] == 0) {
                // alocate memory, set the grade and set the address of the pointer inside the pointer to pointer array.
                int* sub_range_pointer = (int*)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
                if (sub_range_pointer == NULL) {
                    exit(1);
                }
                // save the grade in the memory.
                *sub_range_pointer = Grades[i];
                // set the pointer address in the poinet of pointer array.
                class_grd[place_in_sub_range] = sub_range_pointer;
                // count the number of grades in each range.
                count_grd[place_in_sub_range]++;
                // set the grade in the sum array.
                avg_grd[place_in_sub_range] = Grades[i];
            }
            else {
                // find out how many elemnts is exist, realloc + add new grade and add the grade to there.
                int* sub_range_pointer = (int*)realloc(class_grd[place_in_sub_range], count_grd[place_in_sub_range] * sizeof(int) + sizeof(int));
                if (sub_range_pointer == NULL) {
                    exit(1);
                }
                // set the grade in the relevant range.
                sub_range_pointer[count_grd[place_in_sub_range]] = Grades[i];
                // set the pointer address in the poinet of pointer array.
                class_grd[place_in_sub_range] = sub_range_pointer;
                // raise the number of grades in the relevant range.
                count_grd[place_in_sub_range]++;
                // set the grade in the sum array.
                avg_grd[place_in_sub_range] = (avg_grd[place_in_sub_range] + Grades[i]) / 2;
            }
        }
        //else {
        //  return NULL;
        //}
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sub_range; i++) {
        if (class_grd[i] == 0) {
            class_grd[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    // return the pointer of pointer array.
    return class_grd;
```

so on arr1 my code is working,
but on the arr2 it isn't.

i see that when i take the 45 or 46 grade and divine it in the range i'm inserting it to the 3 index (and it should be the second).
When I'm running the code through  the school test checker i get this error:

```
timeout: the monitored command dumped core ../runTrain.sh: line 1: 21344 Segmentation fault timeout -k 5s 5s ./MainTrain.exe > ./mainTrain.log
```

Comment: `(int**)calloc(sub_range, sizeof(int));` you want to allocate `sub_range` _pointers_ to int, not ints. Tip: `realloc(NULL` is equal to `malloc`. Just `realloc(class_grd[place_in_sub_range` there is  no need to handle the if explicitly. `if (class_grd[i] == 0) {
            class_grd[i] = NULL;` NULL is 0, this is doing nothing.

Comment: i was wrong, i meant to do:
class_grd = (int**)calloc(sub_range, sizeof(int *));

now my code is run in the system. but i still get the problem with the place the grade in the right range.

Comment: I don't understand the grade range thing; how do they get `100/range+1`? It is true that [0..100] contains a prime number of integer elements, so as long as the numbers aren't 1 or 101 it's `floor(101/range)+1`? ASC?

Comment: @Neil if the range on the grades is 10 so you basically have 11 sub-group in that range: 0-9, 10-19,...,90-99, 100 (it's 11 group in of grades), so to get to that number you need to take the maximum grade division it with the rage of the grades and add 1.

another example is: you have range of grades in the value of 15, meaning you have 7 groups of grades ranges: 0-14, 15-30,...., 63-78,..., 95-100.
you get the groups of ranges number again with the same calculation.

Comment: Right, `ceil(n/k) = floor((n-1)/k)+1` for `n > 1, k > 0`, [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/421509).

Comment: What is wrong with `grade/division`. Could you comment on the return type a little more? What is `sub-group by ASC`? What is `count array`? If all that matters is the count of the grades, a [histogram will be appropriate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). However, "need to set NULL," leads me to believe [that a constant hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists) will be more what they are looking for.